# Google sitelink search box with Google custom search

Tags: google-oauth, google-custom-search, google-search-api

We want to implement Google sitelink search box with Google custom search. In the Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview), I found that we need to include the below code to enable sitelink search box

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "WebSite",
   "url": "https://www.example-petstore.com/",
   "potentialAction": {
     "@type": "SearchAction",
     "target": "https://query.example-petstore.com/search?q={search_term_string}",
     "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
   }
}
</script>
```

But we are stuck at "target" node in the above properties. Since we dont have any own search page, we want to use Google custom searh, so what value should I fill in this "target" node.

We have already created a Google custom search engine for our site. And found below code there

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'CX_ID';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

We want to implement sitelink search box like [Mashable](http://mashable.com/), [Imdb](http://www.imdb.com/)

[image]

Please suggest, how to point Google custom search in sitelink search box code.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](http://moz.com/blog/sitelinks-search-box) will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Shishdem . But this link is also pointing to same Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview) :(

Comment: Any other suggestions??

Comment: Nope, not from my side. In my answer I explained what's possible and what's not - obviously you need to dive into the documentation yourself. Or implement a search page - you should be good using google custom search.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution:

For this you need a search page on your own website.

> For the "target" parameter, do a search on your site and take that URL and replace the search term you used to do the search with "{search_term_string}"

If you make a search page on your website where you use a custom Google Search, you should be able to take that link for the `target`-property.

The reason for this is that Google does not supply the search functiop

> will send the user directly to your website's own search pages.

Sources:

- http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ro/2014/09/improved-sitelinks-search-box.html
- http://www.seocandy.co.uk/seo/setup-google-sitelink-search/

Comment: But websites like mashable.com, imdb.com, makemytrip.com do not have any own search page, still sitelink search box is visible in Google SERP. On searching in sitelink search box, it lands on Google SERP with "site:mashable.com" appended in query string.

Comment: they all do have their own search pages. IMDB for example: `http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q={search_term_string}`

Comment: hmm...imdb has own search engine but this search page is not mapped from sitelink search box. It lands again on Google SERP. imdb must have not provided own search page in "target" node .

Answer (score 1):

Shishdem's links do not identify what the write for the target either, after some guess work this works

```
https://example.com/index.html?q={search_term_string}
```

for a search box included as a part of the `index.html` page

if you search box is on the sitemap page use

```
https://examples.com/sitemap.html?q={search_term_string}
```

I was only able to find this because the 404 page included the search box, so it returned 404 then results appeared, so I tweaked the code.

This ignores anything else on that page and appears to come up with the right results, so should fit into the JSON-LD (or microdata if you prefer). JSON-LD might be better since google recommends it but states microdata is accepted. Reference to link in original question documentation.

Comment: Not sure if the sitelinks search box will show up with this target (since I know it takes time for Google to decide on whether to show it or not), but that target links seems to work for me. Link goes straight to the google custom search. FYI, for others, if your site's homepage does not need index.html, you can omit that. So it would just be `https://www.example.com/?q={search_term_string}`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible!

The Community-Manager https://support.google.com/profile/1532198 answered the question.

https://support.google.com/programmable-search/thread/5714081/how-to-get-search-handler-uri-while-setting-up-a-custom-search-engine-on-my-website?hl=en&msgid=5715607

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This feature "Sitelinks" is not available with CSE engine.

Please review the document below for guidance:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox

Answer (score 0):

You will need Google CSE WordPress plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-cse/

1. Install it.
2. Enable Custom Search API
3. Generate API
4. Use the your generated API and custom Search Engine ID
5. Find your built in WordPress search on the site

Now you will be able to use SearchAction Shema.org markup (Sitelink search box).

Only works with WordPress.